# What is the type map in Favimon?

Tags: favimon

Favimon obviously uses a type map where type A is strong against type b.  I've noticed that `google` seems to be strong against `microsoft`.  Is there a listing of these advantages somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made Favimon! At the moment, there is no rock-paper-scissors type system to give some classes an advantage against others. I did have one when I first launched the game, but because there are so many classes, it quickly became unmanageable and almost never affected combat anyway, so I took it out.

Thanks for your interest in my game!

Answer (score 3):

[Classes only really affect the pool of actions available to each favimon.](http://www.matthewhollett.com/favimon/faq.php#faq-database) For example, sites of class stackoverflow could have an 'Addiction' or a 'Tumbleweed' attack; sites of class gaming could have a 'game over' or a 'noticeable lag' attack; sites of class advice could have a 'step-by-step' attack; sites of class 'how-to' could have an 'fyi' attack; etc.

When a favimon appears on the field, four actions are chosen from the pool. For example, gaming.stackexchange.com is of classes 'stackoverflow gaming how-to advice', so it could come equipped with e.g. "Game Over", "Tumbleweed", "Step-by-step" and "Addiction."

Given that there are as of now 286 different classes, I don't think Favimon has a proper rock-paper-scissor system.

Comment: When you hover an action, its associated class is mentioned in the tooltip.